# Rotate figures around non-linear axis

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm looking for a book or publications about interesting cases when 2D figure can be rotated around non-linear axes with some interesting outputs. Simple example - we rotate a circle around the linear x-axis and get a torus.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-linear axes"?

Comment: Based on the torus example, they mean tracing a path rather than rotating around an axis. Imagine sliding a bracelet around a bagel.

Comment: @dbx Yes, you are right. Thank you for the suggestion.